# Custom ActionView::Resolver ignores layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview

I have created a custom `ActionView::Resolver` to pull views from the database instead of the file system. It works - well, almost. It is correctly pulling and rendering the view, but it does not render it inside of a layout! Basically the result is a page with just the view portion (no layout, styling, etc.). Here's what I'm doing:

**DbResolver**

```
class DbResolver < ActionView::Resolver
  require "singleton"
  include Singleton

  @@view_handler = ActionView::Template.registered_template_handler(:erb)

  def find_templates(name, prefix, partial, details)
    if (!prefix.empty?)
      pages = Page.where("`controller_name` = :controller_name AND `action_name` = :action_name", { :controller_name => prefix, :action_name => name })

      templates = pages.collect { |page|
        ActionView::Template.new(page.content, "#{page.class} - #{page.id} - #{page.controller_name}/#{page.action_name}", @@view_handler, {
          :format         => "text/html",
          :updated_at     => page.updated_at,
          :virtual_path   => "#{page.controller_name}/#{page.action_name}"
        })
      }

      return templates
    end
  end
end
```

**BaseController**

```
class BaseController < ApplicationController
  layout "public"
end
```

**ContactController**

```
class ContactController < BaseController
  prepend_view_path Page.resolver

  def index
  end
end
```

**Page**

```
require "lib/db_resolver"

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.resolver
    return DbResolver.instance
  end
end
```

Why is my `layout "public"` being ignored? How do I get this thing to stop ignoring my layouts?

**Update** From the log, I see that Rails is indeed trying to find the `layouts/public` layout - but it's not in the database and my resolver returns `[]`. My understanding was that Rails would then check the file system (default behavior). But instead, it just seems to pretend like all is well and continues:

```
Finding template with: path=about/index; partial=false; details={"formats":["html"],"handlers":["builder","coffee","erb"],"locale":["en"]}
Locating view about/index in database.

Finding template with: path=layouts/about; partial=false; details={"formats":["text/html"],"handlers":["builder","coffee","erb"],"locale":["en"]}
Locating view layouts/about on file system.

Finding template with: path=layouts/public; partial=false; details={"formats":["text/html"],"handlers":["builder","coffee","erb"],"locale":["en"]}
Locating view layouts/public on file system.

Finding template with: path=layouts/public; partial=false; details={"formats":["html","text","js","css","ics","csv","png","jpeg","gif","bmp","tiff","mpeg","xml","rss","atom","yaml","multipart_form","url_encoded_form","json","pdf","zip"],"handlers":["builder","coffee","erb"],"locale":["en"]}
Locating view layouts/public on file system.

Started GET "/about" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Feb 11 22:05:38 -0500 2014
Processing by AboutController#index as HTML
  [1m[36mPage Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `pages`.* FROM `pages` WHERE (`controller_name` = 'about' AND `action_name` = 'index')[0m
  Rendered Page - 1 - about/index (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 19.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved it! I really don't know how this even was the cause of the issue, but this fix works. I had the `:format` parameter set to `text/html` instead of just `html`:

```
ActionView::Template.new(page.content, "#{page.class} - #{page.id} - #{page.controller_name}/#{page.action_name}", @@view_handler, {
  :format         => "html",
  :updated_at     => page.updated_at,
  :virtual_path   => "#{page.controller_name}/#{page.action_name}"
})
```

I changed the `:format => 'text/html'` line to simply `:format => 'html'`. Here is the final DbResolver:

```
class DbResolver < ActionView::Resolver
  @@view_handler = ActionView::Template.registered_template_handler(:erb)

  def initialize(params)
    @exclude_prefixes = (params[:exclude_prefixes] || [])
    super()
  end

  def find_templates(name, prefix, partial, details)
    if (!prefix.empty? && !@exclude_prefixes.include?(prefix))
      pages = Page.where("`controller_name` = :controller_name AND `action_name` = :action_name", { :controller_name => prefix, :action_name => name })

      return pages.collect { |page|
        ActionView::Template.new(page.content, "#{page.class} - #{page.id} - #{page.controller_name}/#{page.action_name}", @@view_handler, {
          :format         => (details[:format] || "html"),
          :updated_at     => page.updated_at,
          :virtual_path   => "#{page.controller_name}/#{page.action_name}"
        })
      }
    end

    return []
  end
end
```

Maybe someone can explain why the `:format` setting "stuck" when I created the first template (for about/index), that same format was then passed back to the resolver when it was trying to find the layout. I assume it is because a layout is expected, by default, to be in the same format as the view. I suppose that makes sense.

Sure would be nice if Rails had some decent documentation!